# Returning an output from two separate tables with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `products` and `assets`. They are joined by a table `assets_products`.

I need to return a table containing all rows from both `products` and `assets`, whilst also showing a count of the number of associated rows for both in `assets_products`.

Not all products have assets and vice versa, and I need to show this with a zero count.

For instance:

```
product   asset    count
 foo        x        1
 bar        x        0
 foo        y        2
 bar        y        1
```

Comment: Can you possibly add an example of what you got and what you want to see as the result?

Comment: try using `Full Outer Join` to get rows and then do `count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select products.product,
       assets.asset,
       COUNT(assets_products.id) as count
from assets
cross join products
left join assets_products
    on (assets_products.asset_id = assets.id and
        assets_products.product_id = products.id)
group by products.product, assets.asset
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.product,a.asset,count(*)
from product p
full outer join product_asset pa 
on pa.product_id=p.product_id
full outer join asset a
on a.asset_id=pa.asset_id
group by p.product_id,a.asset_id
```

Comment: this will not return any missing `products` or `assets`